# android.helpers unit not found

Tags: delphi, android-intent, delphi-xe8

I am trying to use the Unit Androidapi.Helpers, but when I included it in the USES delphi cannot compile the project. I am using Delphi XE 8 and Windows 7.

Delphi shows me the following error: [dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit2.pas(8): F2613 Unit 'Androidapi.Helpers' not found.

But if I search in my folders I can locate this unit at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\lib\android\debug.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does the compile find other Android related units? What is your build target? I hope it's Android.

Comment: You should not need to change anything. This should work out of the box surely.

Comment: Hi Ken, yes the file is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\source\rtl\android. But how can I add the folder tothe project Library, can you explain what is the way to do that?

Comment: @aalmeidasp: You really should not add RTL source folders to your project. Strive to use the pre-compiled RTL DCUs instead of the RTL source `.pas` files directly.

Comment: I got it. It is working now. Thanks Ken, I add the folder to the project library. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let's keep the comments constructive and civil please.

Comment: @aalmeidasp Please don't add the RTL source folder to your library path, or indeed the source file to the project. You need to make sure that the compiler can find the compiled DCU file shipped with the compiler

Answer (score 1):

The `Androidapi.Helpers` unit still exists in XE8.  Double-check your search path configuration, you are probably missing an entry for the folder that contains the DCU that `Androidapi.Helpers` was compiled into.  Also note that there is a `FMX.Helpers.Android` unit as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this;

```
Androidapi.Helpers.SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```